# Fixed position navbar/header works but content won't scroll under header

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi I'm struggling the main content to go underneath the fixed header as the user scrolls down.

Instead of the main body going underneath the header as the user scrolls down...
the main body just moves upwards towards the fixed header...and covers it! rather than it disappearing from view behind the fixed header.

I've looked for many examples..they're helpful but doesn't explain why the main content isn't disappearing behind the fixed header...just moving upwards covering the header.

I've tried adding:

```
position: relative;
```

But it makes the maincontent disappear.

Thanks.

[image: screenshot1]

UPDATED NEW CODE:

index.html

```
<html ng-app="financeApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- CSS -->



 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>



  <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
  <header>





   <div class="wrap">
      <!-- logo -->

   <!--    <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/history_00.png" /></a>
  <h7>Building lasting relationships<h7>-->



<ng-controller = "demoCtrl">

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">



      <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
        <a ui-sref="home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
        <a ui-sref="form">ABOUT US</a>



<li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
          <a href="#candidates">CANDIDATES</a>

</li>

       <li ng-class="{active: isState('jobs') }">
        <a ui-sref="jobs">JOBS</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('joinus') }">
       <a ui-sref="joinus">JOIN US</a>
      </li>


  <li ng-class="{active: isState('contact') }">
        <a ui-sref="contact">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">          </h3>
    <br>
</div>
</header>







<!--<div class="full-background">-->
<div ui-view class="main"></div>





<!--</div>
</div>-->


<!-- Loading the Footer -->
  <div id="footer" ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>

</body>
</html>


   <!-- App JS -->
```

This is more of style.css:

```
 header {
  height:10px;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
height:75px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

header .nav {
 /* float:center;*/
margin: 10px auto 0;
/*position: fixed;*/
/*z-index:1;*/
background: #0783A9;

}
.nav {

  background-color:#0783A9 ;
  color: white;
/* float:center;*/

}
.nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}
.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #cecece;
}
```

Comment: Possibly just a positioning/z-index issue.  Could you provide us a stripped down version of your HTML and the respective styles?  Also, what does this have to do with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state

> I'm struggling the main content to go underneath the fixed header as
>   the user scrolls down.

But the CSS:

```
header .nav {
float:center; /* not a valid setting for float BTW */
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 400px;
position: fixed;
z-index:10;
}
```

means that the `nav` element is fixed and **not** the header.

```
header{
position: fixed;
}

header .nav {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 400px;
}
```

Is **probably** what you are after but without a demo it's hard to be 100% certain.

Comment: I've added 
position: fixed; to header...but it just makes the header disappear?

Comment: You have to set a position & dimensions for the header. See- http://jsfiddle.net/L6go1o8m/

Comment: Thanks but it just makes the main body go on top of the header as the user scrolls down?

Comment: Not in the fiddle it doesn't. If you make a **basic** demo of your existing code we can take it further..at the moment we're working in the dark.

Comment: It'll be difficult to do a jsfiddle as I'm using an angularjs app with many different views and external files.  I've tried making a simplified version of my website on jsfiddle but it won't run properly.

I've edited the above to show more of my code that may be causing it to not to work as it should do?  Thank you.

Comment: It's so strange how the body just moves upwards and covers the header rather than going behind it?

Comment: The nav bar only appears when I set .nav to position fixed.  But partially.

If I set header to position fixed...it disappears.

Comment: If the nav is inside the fixed header you don't need to position it separately.- http://jsfiddle.net/L6go1o8m/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I'm afraid the main body content still goes above the header as the user scrolls down.

Comment: Then, without a meaningful live example, I'm not sure I can help further.

Comment: I've tried to upload my work on jsfiddle and plunker but it won't work properly.

Comment: I added a Z-index:300;  seems to have helped.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `float: centre;` doesn't exist in CSS.

I would recommend using the the following to centre you menu. Only because if the users screen is larger or smaller than your own, then it won't appear centred for them.

```
header .nav {
    background: #0783A9;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Adding a background colour to the `.nav` will stop your content showing through as it is currently transparent.